# Emails transfer

Tags: email, smtp

What is the protocol used to communicate between SMTP server and the receiver host? e.g. I connect to SMTP server and send email data (containing 'To' info in header), how does the SMTP send my email to the specified receiver's server ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inter-SMTP server communication also uses SMTP the same way you communicated with the outgoing SMTP server.